# Tkinter Update list of buttons depending on a click of another list of buttons

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, grid

I am new to tkinter. I have a list of buttons A and when I select one of the buttons I can also update a label (see code). Now I would like to have a second list of buttons B where the number of buttons (and functionality) depends on the click on a button from the list of buttons A (I tried to show this in the picture).

What am I doing wrong here? Can you help me please!

```
import tkinter as tk
  
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Analyser")
root.geometry("750x250")

group_number = tk.StringVar()
l0 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=group_number, width=20)
l0.grid(row=1,column=1)

def func(n):
    group_number.set("Selected Button: Button " + str(n+1))
    

Buttons_A = ["Button 1","Button 2"]

l2 = tk.Label(root, text = "BUTTONS A",font=('Helvetica', 12, "bold"), fg='white', bg='#107baf', width=20)
l2.grid(row=0, column=0,padx=4,pady=8)


for i in range(len(Buttons_A)):
    btn=tk.Button(root, text=Buttons_A[i], font=('Helvetica', 10), bg='#d8e7ea', width=20, activebackground='#42bed8')
    btn.config(command=lambda n=i:func(n))
    btn.grid(row=i+1,column=0, padx=4,pady=4)
    

Buttons_B_1 = ["Button 1","Button 2","Button 3"]
Buttons_B_2 = ["Button 1"]


l2 = tk.Label(root, text = "BUTTONS B",font=('Helvetica', 12, "bold"), fg='white', bg='#107baf', width=20)
l2.grid(row=0, column=2,padx=4,pady=8)


for i in range(len(Buttons_B_1)):
    btn=tk.Button(root, text=Buttons_B_1[i], font=('Helvetica', 10), bg='#d8e7ea', width=20, activebackground='#42bed8')
    btn.config(command=lambda n=i:func(n))
    btn.grid(row=i+1,column=2, padx=4,pady=4)
    
       
root.mainloop()
```

When Button 1 is selected from Button List A:

[image]

When Button 2 is selected from Button List A:

[image]

Comment: keep buttons on list so you could delete them and then you can create new buttons with new text. And create new buttons inside `func()`

Comment: or create buttons inside FRame and then you can delete frame to remove all buttons - and next create new frame with new buttons. Eventually you can first create two frames - one with buttons for `Button1` and second with buttons for Button2 and later hide one frame and show another frame.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep buttons B on list so you could easily destroy them.

When you click button A then it runs `func` and inside this function you should destroy buttons from list, clear this list, create new buttons and add them to this list.

Code will be simpler if you will keep buttons B1 and B2 as sublists on one list.

---

Minimal working code.

I removed fonts and colors to show only important elements.

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def func(n):
    group_number.set(f"Selected Button: Button {n+1}")
    create_buttons_B(n)

def create_buttons_B(selected_button_1):

    # remove previous buttons 
    
    for button in existing_buttons_B:
        button.destroy()

    # clear list

    existing_buttons_B.clear()
    
    # create new buttons and add to list
        
    buttons = Buttons_B[selected_button_1]
    
    for number, text in enumerate(buttons):
        btn = tk.Button(root, text=text)
        btn.grid(row=number+1, column=2)

        existing_buttons_B.append(btn)
        
# --- main ---

Buttons_A = ["Button 1", "Button 2"]

Buttons_B = [
    ["Button B1 1", "Button B1 2", "Button B1 3"],
    ["Button B2 1"],
]    

existing_buttons_B = []  # list for created buttons B

root = tk.Tk()

group_number = tk.StringVar(root)
l0 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=group_number, width=20)
l0.grid(row=1, column=1)

l2 = tk.Label(root, text="BUTTONS A")
l2.grid(row=0, column=0)

for number, text in enumerate(Buttons_A):
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=text, command=lambda n=number:func(n))
    btn.grid(row=number+1, column=0)

l2 = tk.Label(root, text="BUTTONS B")
l2.grid(row=0, column=2)
   
#create_buttons_B(0)  # create buttons at start

root.mainloop()
```

---

Eventually you could use `Frame` to group buttons and then you have to destroy only this `Frame` and it will destroy also buttons.

But you can also first create Frames with buttons and put buttons in frames and later use `grid_forget()` to remove one frame and `grid()` to show another frame.

Answer (score 1):

The two columns of buttons in your application — those in the <kbd>BUTTON A</kbd> list and those in the <kbd>BUTTON B</kbd> list — can be organized into a two level hierarchy and easily be represented in a dictionary like this:

```
BUTTON_GROUPS = {
    "Group 1": ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"],
    "Group 2": ["Button 1"],
}
```

Data in the above format can be used to drive the construction of the rest of the GUI. Since it's desirable to sometimes be able treat the <kbd>BUTTON B</kbd> column buttons as a single compound unit, such as when showing and hiding them, nesting them inside as a separate "container" `tk.Frame` will make that easier because they can all be affected by merely changing *it* instead of dealing with each widget in the group individual.

Here's what I mean:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Analyser")
root.geometry("750x250")

grp_number_var = tk.StringVar()
l0 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=grp_number_var, width=20)
l0.grid(row=1, column=1)

def func(n):
    grp_number_var.set("Selected Button: Button " + str(n))

BUTTON_GROUPS = {
    "Group 1": ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"],
    "Group 2": ["Button 1"],
}

# Label headers.
tk.Label(root, text="BUTTONS A", font=('Helvetica', 12, "bold"),
               fg='white', bg='#107baf', width=20).grid(
               row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=8)
tk.Label(root, text="BUTTONS B", font=('Helvetica', 12, "bold"),
               fg='white', bg='#107baf', width=20).grid(
               row=0, column=2, padx=4, pady=8)

group_buttons = []
button_frames = []

def show_frame(group_btn, btn_frame):
    """Make specified group button active and its associatge button frame
    visible and hide previously one.
    """
    grp_number_var.set('')  # Clear label.

    for btn in group_buttons:
        if btn is group_btn:
            btn.config(bg='#42bed8')
        else:
            btn.config(bg='#d8e7ea')

    for frame in button_frames:
        if frame is btn_frame:
            frame.grid()
        elif frame.winfo_ismapped():
            frame.grid_remove()

# Create BUTTON A column group buttons and associated BUTTON B column buttons.
for row, grp_name in enumerate(BUTTON_GROUPS, start=1):
    # BUTTON A column group button.
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=grp_name, font=('Helvetica', 10),
                    bg='#d8e7ea', width=20)
    btn.grid(row=row, column=0, padx=4, pady=8, sticky='n')
    group_buttons.append(btn)

    btn_frame = tk.Frame(root)
    num_btns = len(BUTTON_GROUPS[grp_name])  # Number of buttons in 2nd column.
    btn_frame.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='n', rowspan=num_btns)
    btn_frame.grid_remove()  # Initially invisible.
    button_frames.append(btn_frame)

    # Configure column button to toggle button frame's visibility.
    btn.config(command=lambda group_btn=btn, btn_frame=btn_frame:
                            show_frame(group_btn, btn_frame))

    # BUTTON B column buttons.
    for i, sub_group_btn in enumerate(BUTTON_GROUPS[grp_name], start=1):
        btn = tk.Button(btn_frame, text=sub_group_btn, font=('Helvetica', 10),
                        bg='#d8e7ea', width=20, activebackground='#42bed8')
        btn.config(command=lambda n=i: func(n))
        btn.grid(row=row+i, column=2, padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Here's a screenshot showing what's initially displayed, followed by two more showing what happens when corresponding group button is clicked:

[image: screenshot nothing selected]

[image: screenshot group button 1 selected]

[image: screenshot group button 2 selected]

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to associate the required lists using *dictionary* for `Buttons_A` instead of separated lists:

```
Buttons_A = {
    "Button 1": ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"],
    "Button 2": ["Button 1"]
}
```

Also better use frames to group buttons, so that you can just destroy buttons in "BUTTONS B" and then create new ones whenever a button in "BUTTONS A" is clicked.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Analyser")
root.geometry("750x250")

group_number = tk.StringVar()
l0 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=group_number, width=20)
l0.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='n')

def func(btn):
    group_number.set("Selected Button: "+btn)
    # clear current buttons shown in frame_B
    for w in frame_B.winfo_children():
        w.destroy()
    # populate required buttons
    for item in Buttons_A[btn]:
        btn = tk.Button(frame_B, text=item, font=('Helvetica', 10), bg='#d8e7ea', width=20, activebackground='#42bed8')
        btn.pack(padx=4, pady=4)


Buttons_A = {
    "Button 1": ["Button 1", "Button 2", "Button 3"],
    "Button 2": ["Button 1"]
}

l2 = tk.Label(root, text="BUTTONS A", font=('Helvetica', 12, "bold"), fg='white', bg='#107baf', width=20)
l2.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=4, pady=8)

# frame for "Buttons A"
frame_A = tk.Frame(root)
frame_A.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='n')

for item in Buttons_A:
    btn = tk.Button(frame_A, text=item, font=('Helvetica', 10), bg='#d8e7ea', width=20, activebackground='#42bed8')
    btn.config(command=lambda x=item:func(x))
    btn.pack(padx=4, pady=4)

l2 = tk.Label(root, text="BUTTONS B", font=('Helvetica', 12, "bold"), fg='white', bg='#107baf', width=20)
l2.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=4, pady=8)

# frame for "Buttons B"
frame_B = tk.Frame(root)
frame_B.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='n')

root.mainloop()
```